# Преобразование даты времени из строки в QDateTime с помощью QDateTime::fromString

Tags: c++, qt

Написал вот такой код:

```
    QDateTime dt = QDateTime::fromString("03.мар.20 10:06:15", "dd.MMM.yy hh:mm:ss");
    qDebug() << dt;
```

Получил `QDateTime("ср мар 3 10:06:15 1920")` ,а должен как понимаю получить `03.мар.20 10:06:15`.

Comment: при компиляции компилятор выдает какие-либо варнинги? Они хоть у вас включены?

Comment: В данном случае нет ошибки, в консоль оно выводится в формате системы (Qt::TextDate), если не ошибаюсь, если вам надо выводить дату в определенном формате, то используйте QDateTime::toString, `qDebug() << dt.toString("dd.MMM.yy hh:mm:ss");`

Comment: Проблема в годе? С этим вы ничего не сделаете, можно только прибавлять к результату 100 лет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю дело в годе (1920 вместо 2020).

В текстовом формате у вас только две последние цифры года и Qt привязывает дату к Unix Epoch. "Эпоха" отсчитывается с 1 января 1970 года, а это как вы понимаете прошлый век. И конвертация последних двух цифр года всегда даст 19xx год.
Как в комментариях уже отметили - прибавляейте 100лет:

```
QDateTime dt = QDateTime::fromString("03.мар.20 10:06:15", "dd.MMM.yy hh:mm:ss").addYears(100);
```